# Gmaps function loadGeojson

Tags: google-maps, geojson, google-datalayer

I need to read a GeoJSON select a line according to the search made by the user and then draw it on the map. Until this moment I am doing as in the code below, I walk the property, locate the line and step into a variable to plot on the map using the `loadGeoJson` function. But the function expects a URL, how can I pass a variable with GeoJSON?

```
var onibusLayer = new google.maps.Data(); 
var linhaSearch ;
var linhaGeom ;

function loadOnibus(){  
  linhaSearch =  $('#linha').val() ;

  var url = "/data/onibus.json";

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    beforeSend: function(){
       $('#loader').show();
    },   
    success:(function(data){
          $('#loader').hide();

          for (var i = 0; i < data.features.length; i++) {
            if (data.features[i].properties.CODLIN == linhaSearch){
                linhaGeom = data.features[i];                   
                overlayLine();
                break;
            }
          } 

    }),
    error:(function(data,jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log ("Error load file: " + url +" Status: " + textStatus  );
    })          
  });  
}

function overlayLine(){
  onibusLayer.loadGeoJson(linhaGeom, showLoading(),function(features){    
    hideLoading(); 
    onibusLayer.setMap(map);        
  });    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.addGeoJson` rather than `.loadGeoJson`